# c# How to update variable value in loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've try to loop and from the below code, The problem is when it loop back to “IEnumerable selectedRows =”. The value of DateStart and DateEnd remain the same “9/1/2003 2:00:00” and “9/1/2003 2:59:00” respectively as its initial value. Why the “IEnumerable selectedRows =” do not update the DateTime value? Please help and thank you.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows =
    dtData
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row =>
            row.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= DateStart
            && row.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= DateEnd);

foreach (DataRow row in selectedRows)
{

    //Do some stuffs

}

//store the result in DataTable
DataRow dtDataRowResult = dtDataResult.NewRow();
dtDataRowResult[0] = DateStart;
dtDataRowResult[1] = result1;
dtDataRowResult[2] = result2;
dtDataResult.Rows.Add(dtDataRowResult);

//when code go this line below,
//it should be added one hour from the previous hour,
//so now it is “9/1/2003 3:00:00”
DateStart = DateStart.AddHours(1);
//and the DateEnd should be added to “9/1/2003 3:59:00”
DateEnd = DateStart + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(59);
//The problem is when it loop back to
//“IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows =”.
//The value of DateStart and DateEnd remain the same 
//“9/1/2003 2:00:00” and “9/1/2003 2:59:00” respectively
//as the initial value. Why the
//“IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows =” not updated the
//DateTime value? Please help and thank you.
```

The below is the screenshot image of the example code

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to properly format all the code (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), remove the screenshot (which really isn't useful) and write the text of your question as *actual text* separate from your code, instead of as a comment.

Comment: (It's also not clear why you've tagged c#-4.0 or csharpcodeprovider. There's no evidence of CSharpCodeProvider being relevant, and I doubt that your question is *actually* specific to C# version 4.0, which is now over a decade old.)

Comment: It also doesn't help that we can't see the declaration of `DateStart` and `DateEnd`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: For the DateStart and DateEnd you can see in the image attached in the post. I've edited the post because some said that the post is confusing.

Comment: Your code as above does not compile. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ln8elO   So there is code that we can't see.  For anyone to help you, you need a minimal reproducible example as per @JonSkeet

Comment: "For the DateStart and DateEnd you can see in the image attached in the post." All the code should be presented as *text*, as per my first comment, with the screenshot removed. (It doesn't help that you're not following .NET naming conventions - `DateStart` looks like a property, not a local variable...)

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I've produced a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2023, 1, 9, 2, 0, 0);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow[0] = dateTime;
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);

Console.WriteLine($"{dateTime} == {(DateTime)dataTable.Rows[0][0]}");

dateTime += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(59.0);

Console.WriteLine($"{dateTime} != {(DateTime)dataTable.Rows[0][0]}");
```

When I run that I get this output:

```
2023/01/09 02:00:00 == 2023/01/09 02:00:00
2023/01/09 02:59:00 != 2023/01/09 02:00:00
```

The value in the `DataTable` does not update when I update the `dateTime` variable.

This is because when `dateTime += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(59.0);` is called the value in the variable `dateTime` is updated, but the variable stored in the `DataTable` is a copy of the original `dateTime` value. It's not linked in any way.

To make it update you would need to run this code:

```
dataTable.Rows[0][0] = dateTime;
```

Now we can see it is the same with this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{dateTime} == {(DateTime)dataTable.Rows[0][0]}");
```

That produces:

```
2023/01/09 02:59:00 == 2023/01/09 02:59:00
```